# BuddyBoss Member DIrectory Search function "recent", "newest" & "alphabetical"

Tags: buddypress, buddyboss

I just tried the BuddyPress plugin BP Search.
It allows to create a search form for users to search for specific profile info of members.

The plugin also works with BuddyBoss.
However BuddyBoss has one additionally search function with which users can filter results according to "newest", "recent" or "alphabetical".
The issue is that the BP Search form and BuddyBoss filter option are separated on the page.

The search form comes at the top and below is the BB filter option, they are separated which is why I cannot move the filter up via CSS.
Is there a way to integrate the BuddyBoss filter option in the BP Search form by any chance?

I tried some CSS but realized the form and the filter function are 2 separate issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BuddyBoss has its own profile search. In fact, it is a fork of the BP Profile Search plugin.

Go to wp-admin > BuddyBoss > Profiles > Profile Search.

afaik - you cannot combine the Recently Active etc. filter with the BuddyBoss Profile Search.

Comment: Hi, may I instead ask a slightly different question then: BP or BuddyBoss to be more specific shows a dropdown button next to the grid/list option above the member directory loop.User can filter the member loop according to "newest" "recent" and "alphabetical" members. This filter option is a dropdown button. Is there any chance to turn this one button into 3? So that "recent", "newest" and "alphabetical" each would have their own button to click on? These buttons could sit side by side (not below each other).

Comment: If you found my answer useful - please accept it by clicking on the checkmark.  Then we can discuss your next question.